# Matlab incorrect computation result

Tags: matlab

I got a few Matlab code to play. But the answer is not correct:

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 10)

sinc = @(x) sin(x) ./ x

sinc(x) // wrong result occurs at here.
```

The expected result as below:

```
ans =

  Columns 1 through 6:

  3.8982e-17   2.6306e-01   5.6425e-01   8.2699e-01   9.7982e-01   9.7982e-01

Columns 7 through 10:

  8.2699e-01   5.6425e-01   2.6306e-01   3.8982e-17
```

real result:

```
ans =
 Columns 1 through 3
  0.000000000000000   0.263064408273866   0.564253278793615
 Columns 4 through 6
  0.826993343132688   0.979815536051016   0.979815536051016
 Columns 7 through 9
  0.826993343132688   0.564253278793615   0.263064408273866
 Column 10
  0.000000000000000
```

details: My OS is arch linux, 
         Matlab is downloaded through official website.

matlab version is 2015b

Comment: Those are the same...?

Comment: Yup they are. just the difference of output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected result and the real results you present are identical as far as I can see.

The only difference is the notation: `normal` vs `scientific`.
With `format short` you can switch to `scientific` notation and get identical results with identical formatting.

Comment: Thanks man, it was an enlightenment AHA! Now I solved the problem.